# C# - Get chrome active tab url taking more time

Tags: c#, google-chrome, url

I have been trying to get the google chrome active tab URL using the following code. On some computers like the i7 processor, it is taking roughly 3 seconds to get the URL. However, on i5 and i3 processor computers it is coming quite faster. Is there any way to get the URL in less than a second? Any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
            {
                if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }                

                AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
                if (elmUrlBar != null)
                {
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine(val.Current.Value);
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```